# JavaScript - Stream of JPEGs for poor man's video

Tags: javascript, video, streaming

I'm looking to try and work out how to stream a series of JPEGs as a video using JavaScript. I would like some input as to whether what I'm thinking is feasible or not.

Using a circular buffer, precache the first n images. As each image is displayed, once the next one appears replace the previous element with a new one from the list, such that it loops back over itself creating the illusion of an infinite buffer. Timing (frame rate) could be controlled using the time library and we simply update the src attribute of an image element at the correct interval so it gives the illusion of video.

Is this achievable with Javascript? I assume a limitation would be how long the script takes to run - which would be dependent upon the number of images that need to be shown. Obviously not expecting blistering performance either, just enough to show some motion is fine. This is obviously a very ugly hack.

Comment: It is possible.. for a neat usage look at http://www.360langstrasse.sf.tv/page/

Comment: Did you ask this yesterday under a different name?

Comment: @epascarello - Nope, sure didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is achievable if that answers your question ;)

You can precache the images with

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "url";
```

This way the image should be saved also in browser's cache.

And then using `settimeout(function, timems)` you just change the src of the current image in page.

Comment: Any idea on what sort of frame rate I would expect? Would 25 frames/sec be pushing it?

Comment: that needs to be tried. It depends on the internet connection speed, the size of the images and the computing power of the client.
But I would start somewhere about 10/ sec and you'll see

Comment: OK this doesn't seem to work well at all. I've even slowed it down to 5 fps and it just can't seem to handle it. I think I may need to work on how I'm caching the images, but it just doesn't seem to work properly. They aren't big frames either, 320x240 and about 4mb in total. Definitely not useful for what I want if it can't handle that sort of frame. Any suggestions?

Comment: try to create an html divs with all the images. In css set them to be on same absolute position, and then, in javascript manipulate their z-index ;) it's a hack, but you want one, right? ;)